Is there any existing C implementation(s) in which a (standard) headers are not source files?
Out of curiosity: is there any existing C implementation(s) in which a (standard) headers are not source files?
Reason of the question: C11, 7.1.2 Standard headers, footnote 182 (emphasis added):

A header is not necessarily a source file, nor are the < and > delimited sequences in header names necessarily valid source file names.


In any case, that is also a different question from whether headers are provided as source files.  That does not require the header identifiers used in #include statements in C source files to also be filenames by which a corresponding source file can be accessed through the OS's general-purpose file access interfaces.
